# Помогите пожалуйста создать базу данных для онлайн кинотеатра

Tags: база-данных

В общем у меня 4 таблицы: **профили пользователей**, **каталог фильмов**, **подписки** и **история просмотров**. Никак не пойму, как правильно связать несколько фильмов к одной определенной подписке.
Подписку к профилю, историю просмотров к каталогу фильмов и к профилям пользователей.

Comment: связи многие ко многим реализуются через дополнительную таблицу, где будет пара айдишников от обеих сущностей

Comment: Если надо сделать историю просмотров, то должно быть  не только таблица юзер и филь, но и таблица связи `user_id, film_id, watch_date`

Comment: то есть получается нужно создать отдельную таблицу,чтобы распределить фильмы по подпискам?

Comment: @teran так у него ж уже есть таблица истории просмотров- зачем ещё одна?

Comment: @Akina как пример связи с атрибутами.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте таблицу с полями "ИдФильма" и "ИдПодписки".
Еще одну таблицу с полями "ИдПодписки" и "ИдПрофиля".
И таблицу с полями "ИдФильма" и "ИдПрофиля".

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Схема связывания таблиц]

По поводу подписки мне не совсем понятно как должно работать(знать бы структуру таблиц и как должно работать), с ходу вот такое получилось. Будут какие то дополнения по функционалу и наполнению, можно развивать.